# Short AlertDialog without any listener

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I've googled & I've StackOverflowed but no good answer.

Im from .NET (C#) and there is something like:

```
MessageBox.Show("My Title","My Dialogtext", MessageBoxButtons.OK).ShowDialog();
```

Now my question is: is there ANY method nearly as short as the one above for showing an `AlertDialog` in java?

All the example I've seen are 5 Lines+ of code and all of them with some Listener in it.

I just want a Box with an OK button, nothing more, no listener on click no other stuff.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the shortest one to make an `AlertDialog` in Android, without any listener, and reduce the amount of code required using method chaining

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("My Title").setMessage("My Dialogtext").setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
```

With a title and message you want

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any action to happen when the OK Button clicked, i think this is the shortest code for an AlertDialog.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("My Title");
        builder.setMessage("My Dialogtext");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a snackbar.

https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/showing

You can later add action to it.